# How do I include an apostrophe in the string passed to DataTable Select()?

Tags: ado.net, datatable

The `dt.Select(string)` gives error `missing operand` when `apostrophe` symbol is in the string.

what is the way to solve this error? or How to handle this error?

Comment: Please provide more context? Why is this tagged with asp.net-mvc?

Comment: You need to escape the apostrophe, post your code then we can help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
String value = "Rubens' Home"; // value you want to sanitize and search
dt.Select(String.Format(
    "Location = '{0}'", value.Replace("'", "''")));
```

Comment: I don't know what is value used for can u please make it little clear that what to pass in value

Comment: It is not working the error is String.Replace does not accept 3 overloads