# Error in datatable select statement in c#

Tags: c#

I have a `SELECT` statement I'm running on a data table. The problem is that it gives me the error "the expression contains an invalid string constant". I know it has to do with the single quote at the end of my query but i cannot think of why its not working. Here is the code:

```
DataRow[] foundRow = dt.Select("Student='" + Student.ID + "' AND [Student Description]='" + Student.AbsenceDescription.Trim() + "'");
```

Comment: Is it possible that your student description contains a single quote?

Comment: You shouldn't dynamically generate queries like this, there is a possibility of SQL injection and dozen of other problems you could introduce to your program.

Comment: what is an alternative way to query then?

Comment: @Greg - Try using parameterized queries. Check this link out: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Comment: This looks to be for sql statements. I am working with a datatable though. How does that translate to table syntax?

Comment: What is the result of `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Student='" + Student.ID + "' AND [Student Description]='" + Student.AbsenceDescription.Trim() + "'");`

Comment: where can i find this result? I basically did a print line of the query string before the table ran the select and i got: Student='GregK' AND Student Description='Absent'

Comment: I get the following:
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SyntaxErrorException' occurred in System.Data.dll
The thread '<No Name>' (0x248) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Can you list out the value of Absence description here then please at the point where it breaks? Also - have you checked that Student ID is actually a string? If it isn't you shouldn't wrap it in single quotes (i.e. if that's an integer or auto-incrementing ID etc in your DB remove the ' from around it)

Comment: `Student='GregK' AND Student Description='Absent'` ? Where did the [] round Student Description go?

Comment: Sigh, im an idiot. Its actually a very simple overlooked syntax. I just used breakpoints to track the error and apparently i am doing another query right after that doesnt end with a single quote at the end of the query. Thats where the real error is. So it was like Student='GregK .... forehead slapping moment

Comment: Rubens have provided an answer here.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906384/how-do-i-include-an-apostrophe-in-the-string-passed-to-datatable-select][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906384/how-do-i-include-an-apostrophe-in-the-string-passed-to-datatable-select

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a classic SQL injection problem. What if the description contains a single apostrophe i.e. "Wasn't available", this will break your code. In addition, if Student is an integer value (i.e. it is an integer/auto-incrementing ID or equivalent in your DB) it should not be wrapped in quotes, giving you -

```
DataRow[] foundRow = dt.Select("Student=" + Student.ID + " AND [Student Description]='" + Student.AbsenceDescription.Trim() + "'");
```

Comment: i can gurantee it does not contain any quotes in the description

Comment: i know for a fact that the expression does not have a quote in it already. why is the error still there?

Comment: Another potential is if the absence description is empty. '' is a special character in SQL which is interpreted as an escaped quote. You may want to do a check on Student.AbsenceDescription to ensure its not empty (i.e. !String.IsNullOrEmpty) before filtering

Comment: The description is not empty and the above Replace("'","''") does not work