# Rowfiltering fails when filter text is having single quote

Tags: c#, datatable, rowfilter

As my tiltle clearly mentions I am trying to filter the datatable with a filter text having single quote in it .

My statement is as follows

```
dgURComments.ItemsSource).ToTable().Select("URComments = '" + txtComments.Text.Trim() + "'");
```

How can I overcome from this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include an apostrophe in the string passed to DataTable Select()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906384/how-do-i-include-an-apostrophe-in-the-string-passed-to-datatable-select)

Comment: saying "it fails" is not helpful. You should always describe exactly how it failed, what exceptions were thrown, what the observed results were compared to the expected results, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fiddling around with `DataTable.Select` i would use [`Linq-To-DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977):

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows =  tbl.AsEnumerable()
       .Where(r => r.Field<String>("URComments") == txtComments.Text.Trim());
```

If you need a DataTable from the filtered result, you can use `CopyToDataTable`

```
DataTable tblFiltered = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

<sub>The minimum requirement is a reference to `System.Core.dll` and a using directive for `System.Linq`. By default, these are supplied if you create a new Visual C# 2008 project. `LINQ to DataSet` also requires a reference to `System.Data.dll` and `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` and an using  directive.</sub>